# Square wave RL oscillator

Tags: oscillator, schmitt-trigger

So, I found this nifty oscillator & have been playing with it to generate square waves:
[image]
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HfyMNSJ3phSvn3KAczzim-cAPSgw-3Rp/view (Ctrl+S on the text view)

As far as I understand the first stage, square waves should've been generated. Instead, its triangle waves. So, I pass it to a second stage, with near the peaks as the threshold. Still, it's triangle waves. What am I misunderstanding here?

Also, for procuring the parts, do most product manufacturers go for an op-amp for Schmitt Triggers, or are IC versions common enough to opt for them?

Comment: I think this is not a real world circuit. 100 nH and 100 kohm are an absurd combination.

Comment: How does the rise time of the Schmitt trigger inverters compare to your oscillator period?

Comment: There are logic inverters with Schmitt trigger inputs. But you get the thresholds built into them; which may vary with supply V, temperature, etc.

Comment: My mistake. I started from another oscillator schematic (an RC oscillator) to make sure I have the same Schmitt Trigger setting. That, & I haven't worked with inductors that much to see if those are parasitic. How about 1mH & 1kohm? That scales nicely to a few hundred kHz scale. Come to think of it, once I used these values, I get square waves now.

Comment: @TempusNomen If you just want an oscillator then you don't need anything else but a `Schmitt` gate with `td` set. Just feed back the inverting input and you have a square wave generator.

Comment: The circuit is actually taken from here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/80280/lr-oscillators-no-capacitor. Says Andy aka in part came up with this, so I'm waiting for his response.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I'll try it later in simulation, but is that even real world implementation?

Comment: @TempusNomen You can find a chain of buffers/inverters with the output of the last feeding the input of the first. It relies on the cumulated delay to provide the period, as inaccurate as it may be. Instead of that chain, an RC (instead of an RL) is used. But since you're talking of the real world, why would you discard RC infavour of RL? An L is difficult to make, and prone to be bulkier than the C.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen A 100nH is tiny enough to be SMD. The truth is, I disapprove of parasitic capacitances skewing small capacitor's total effective capacitance. To be effective on the frequencies for which one is using these small capacitors, I believe inductors are small enough for the most part.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen "L is difficult to make". L is just a ferrite core with wire spun around it, very mechanizable. "[L] prone to be bulkier than C". Yes, but in terms of energy density, isn't an L still more dense?

Comment: @TempusNomen If you think an L is going to have less parasitics, you should check a few datasheets for Cs and Ls and see how their frequency graphs are virtually identical (save reversed slopes). If your purpose is speed (the 100 nH in your example) then you're better off using a chain of gates. Otherwise, L or C, they have about the same tolerances. As always, it's a matter of choices. What I proposed with `td` was for the purpose of simulation.